# Does EOS utility fully work with other (non canon) lenses?

Tags: canon, autofocus, software, eos-utility

I only used canon lenses with EOS Utility before and now I'm looking to buy a new sigma lens.

My question is: would fine focus adjustments when shooting tethered still work with other lenses?

[image]

Edit: If anyone finds this later, just got the lens and can confirm it does indeed work, no problems.

Comment: @MichaelC I'm talking about this: https://i.imgur.com/whksTRa.jpg

Comment: @MichaelC https://i.imgur.com/yuHBr6D.jpg when you open "Live view shoot" you can manually adjust focus by small incriments. I'm using 70D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the lens in question will autofocus when using viewfinder based PDAF autofocus or when using Live View directly on the camera, it should also respond to input from the remote Live View window when shooting tethered.

If the Sigma lens you are considering is supposed to autofocus properly when attached to a Canon EOS camera, then it should also respond to AF inputs communicated from a tethered computer via the camera. In both cases the lens is receiving the same instruction from the camera/lens interface, regardless of whether the instruction originated from the tethered computer or from the camera's controls.

Keep in mind that older third party lenses [may have firmware issues](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/83122/15871) with newer camera models. Sigma (and Tamron) now have USB docks that can be used to update the firmware of their latest lenses by the end user when needed.

Comment: The lens I'm looking to buy: https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/806377-REG/Sigma_258101_105mm_f_2_8_EX_DG.html

Comment: That lens was introduced in 2011, two years after the 7D you are using. So it should be good with the original 7D. It is not one of the recent Sigma "Global Vision (ART, Sport, Contemporary) Series" that is compatible with their USB dock. If you are using the 7D Mark II, I'd confirm with the seller that current new copies work with it. Or you could consider the latest version of [Tamron's excellent 90mm Macro](https://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Tamron-90mm-f-2.8-Di-VC-USD-Macro-F017-Lens.aspx). For $80 more it is a lot more future proof since it can be updated via Tamron's USB dock.

Comment: I never said anything about 7D. I'm using 70D.

Comment: Oops. Misread that. SInce the 70D was introduced in 2013, two years after the Sigma lens in questions, I'd definitely check to be sure there are no general compatibility issues with that lens and newer Canon camera. But if it works on your camera it should also work when shooting tethered.