# Can I use APS-C Pentax K mount lenses on Canon EOS 90D?

Tags: canon, lens-adapter, pentax, adapter, k-mount

I currently own seven Pentax K mount lenses which I'm very attached to and spend lot of money on. They been used with Pentax K20D, and now I'm looking to upgrade cameras.

I like the idea of the new APS-C camera Canon EOS 90D. Can you please advise if after buying adapter I will be able to use my lenses 100%? Or might some qualities might work?

I was also considering getting Pentax K-70 or Pentax KP, but I think this Canon is better overall.

Comment: "I will be able to use my lenses 100%?" - Probably not, but depends on the lenses.  What lenses do you have?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000/can-i-use-lens-brand-x-on-interchangeable-lens-camera-brand-y)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to continue using your seven Pentax lenses, your best option would be to upgrade to a better Pentax camera.

There are mechanical adapters that allow Pentax K-mount lenses to be the correct distance from the sensor so that infinity focus is possible with Canon EF mount cameras. But you're going to give up almost all automation: autofocus and any exposure mode that requires the camera to set the aperture setting (which you'll need to set manually on the lens). You'll almost certainly be wasting most of the capability that attracted you to Canon EOS 90D in the first place.

If you want to use the Canon EOS 90D, you'll only get maximum performance out of it using Canon EF and EF-S lenses, or third party lenses made in the Canon EF mount that are [up to date in terms of firmware](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/83122/15871).